# Create a BigQuery view to get the latest rows from a partitioned (and clustered) table

Tags: google-bigquery

## The issue

I'm trying to create a view to get the latest rows from a partitioned table, filtered on the date partition `_LOCALDATETIME` and zero or more cluster fields.  I can create a view which uses a partition and I can create a view which handles some filters, but I can't work out the syntax to achieve both.

### An example query requirement

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC FROM theView
WHERE date between '2021-01-01' and '2021-12-31' AND
  _CLUSTERFIELD1 = 'foo'
GROUPBY _CLUSTERFIELD2
ORDERBY _CLUSTERFIELD3
```

## Table schema

```
_LOCALDATETIME
_id
_CLUSTERFIELD1
_CLUSTERFIELD2
_CLUSTERFIELD3
_CLUSTERFIELD4
...other fields
```

Comment: Hello, just for clarification. You want use view which already have filtered partitioned data? as partitioned data. I think you are hitting the limitations of partitioning as it will not be a [top field](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#limitations)

Comment: The table is already partitioned by `_LOCALDATETIME` and clustered on the indicated fields/ The requirement is to fetch the latest row, based on the `_id` for any query which has filtered by partition and cluster

Answer (score 0):

Base on what I'm understanding from your case I have come with this approach.
I have created partion table based on `_LOCALDATETIME` with clustered fields and then the view that returns the data from a defined date scope and the value of the last elements based on `_id`. So, that will allow me to have a view which have the last items of a partitioned table from a fixed date range.

**view**

```
CREATE VIEW `<my-project-id>.<dataset>.<table>` AS
  with range_id as (
    select MAX(_id) as last_id_partition,_localdatetime as partition_ FROM
    `<my-project-id>.<dataset>.<table>` where _localdatetime BETWEEN "2020-01-01" and "2022-01-01" group by _localdatetime)
  SELECT s.*
  FROM
    `<my-project-id>.<dataset>.<table>` s
  inner join range_id r on s._id = r.last_id_partition and s._localdatetime = r.partition_ 
  where _localdatetime BETWEEN "2020-01-01" and "2022-01-01"
  group by _id,_localdatetime,_name,_location
```

The view will return the last ids of a partioned clustered table with the clustered fields that are within the view (which is for year 2020 and 2021).

**query**

```
select * from `<my-project-id>.<dataset>.<table>`
WHERE  _localdatetime between '2021-12-21' and '2021-12-22'
and <clusteredfield> = 'Venezuela'
```

It will return the records available for that filter as the data its already [defined](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro) in the view.

What you can't do is to have a view without the partition field as it must exist to query a partitioned table. You can also update use the queries inside a [function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#calling_persistent_user-defined_functions_udfs) to further customize your outputs.

Comment: There is only one table. Is this not possible without a join?

Comment: Well I use `with` to get the list of last_ids of the table ( if its unique you can use it without the _localdatetime).  The  `join` is just to get every other records the table may need. About using without the join .. ( and I'm assuming without the `with` ) you will have to use the query from the `with` section and also grouping every single column you want to add.